# Arithmetic structure of non-zero cumulants

Tags: pr.probability, cumulants

It is known that any non-Gaussian distribution must have infinitely many non-zero cumulants (Marcinkiewicz). I was wondering if something stronger is known about the structure of non-zero cumulants. In particular,  $\mathbf{X}$ is a non-Gaussian random variable and define $A_{\mathbf{X}} = \{i: $ the $i^{th}$ cumulant of $\mathbf{X}$ is non-zero$\}$. Is there a lower bound on the density of the  $A_{\mathbf{X}}$  in $\mathbb{N}$ (say some fixed $c>0$)? How sparse can the set $A_{\mathbf{X}}$ be?

Comment: Well, $A_X$  is a subset of $2\mathbb{N}$ whenever $X$ (with all cumulants assumed to exist) is symmetrically distributed. So $A_X$ needn't have density $1$.

Comment: If $4\le r\in2\mathbb{N}$, then we can have $A_X\subseteq 2\mathbb{N}\setminus\{r\}$. (Proof: The $r$th cumulant $f_r(p)$ of the binomial law $\mathrm{B}_p=(1-p)\delta_0+p\delta_1$ is known to satisfy the recursion $f_1(p)=p$, $f_{r+1}(p)=p(1-p)f_r'(p)$; hence, by Rolle,  $f_r(p)=0$ for some $p\in\mathopen]0,1\mathclose[$ if $r\ge3$. Take $X=X_1-X_2$ with $X_1,X_2$ i.i.d. $\mathrm{B}_p$.) Can anyone provide a strictly smaller upper bound for any $A_X$?

Comment: I guess I was not very clear on what I meant by saying $A_{\mathbf{X}}$ is dense -- what I meant by a dense set is that is it case that $A_{\mathbf{X}}$ necessarily at least has some density $c>0$ in $\mathbb{N}$? Or could it be the case that say the set $A_{\mathbf{X}}$ has $o(1)$ density?